# Laravel: Buscando como pasar datos desde un controlador a una vista

Tags: laravel

Me surge una duda y como soy muuuuyyy novato en laravel y no entiendo mucho me gustaría ver si hay alguien con experiencia que me saque una duda.

El proyecto le cargue el Auth de laravel el cual me carga un Register controller y en el cual sobre escribo el método

```
public function showRegistrationForm()
{

    $empresas = Empresa::All();
  //  dd($empresa);



   1- return view('auth.register',['empresas' => $empresas]);


    2- return view('auth.register', compact('$empresas'));
}
```

Ahora el tema es para pasar datos desde el controlador a la vista: Si utilizo el método 1 los datos llegan, pero si utilizo el 2 no llegan y me arroja error.

Utilizo laravel 7, también probé con withData pero nada.

Comment: ¿Qué error te regresa la segunda opción?

Comment: Bueno es solo una opinión al no conocer que error obtienes con la segunda opción, si con la primera te funciona no veo mayor dificultad

Comment: El error es que la variable $empresas no es encontrada en la vista.

Comment: Prueba pasar la variable sin el símbolo de dólar al inicio cuando tratas de usar compact, ya en el sitio existe una pregunta y solución al respecto si la encuentro te la dejo en los comentarios

Comment: Probe sacar el $: no arroja error pero tampoco llegan los datos.

Comment: No tiene nada de malo la primera opcion, de echo es la mas recomendada para pasar datos a la vista, en la vista tambien haz un var_dump o dd para ver que informacion llega

Comment: Dohko19 Mi estimado no digo que una sea mejor que la otra, simplemente busco el xq una funciona y la otra no, siendo que según la documentación oficial es lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como te comenta BetaM, debes quitar el simbolo $ del parametro compact...

en tu controlador:

```
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
   $empresas = Empresa::all();
   return view('auth.register', compact('empresas'));
}
```

en tu vista:

```
<table>
    @foreach ($empresas as $item)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $item->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Dado que no pasaba los parámetros y a su vez tenía otros errores incomprensibles re instale y por ahora funciona bien.